# SelectInput and dateRangeinput functions

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, shiny-reactivity

I really need your help. I am new in R shiny and I have to use 2 reactives functions. I have a table of a DataBase which columns `(id_cli, val_cli, date_cli)` example `(1, 12, 2020-02-01); (1,30,2020-02-02); (2, 80,2020-02-03), etc` the `id_cli` is foreign key, so it isnt unique in this table. I want to select the `id_cli` using the function `selectInput` and from there select a date range using the `dateRangeInput` function

This is my code :

```
DB <- dbConnect(MySQL(), 
                user='xx', 
                host='xxx.xxx.x.xx')

req22 = dbGetQuery(DB, "select id_cli, val_cli, date_cli from t_client;")

agg22 = setNames(aggregate(req22[,1:2], list(req22$date_cli), mean), c("date_cli", "id_cli","val_cli"))

agg22$date_cli = as.Date(agg22$date_cli)

dates22 <- seq(from = min(agg22$date_cli),
             to = max(agg22$date_cli),
             by="days") 

tweets22 <- data.frame(dateW = dates22, agg22$val_cli, agg22$id_cli)

selectInput(inputId = "id_cli2", label = h3("List of clients"), choices = tweets22$agg22.id_cli)


dateRangeInput(inputId="dateW", label ="Selectionne a Date",
            start = min(tweets22$agg22.date_cli), 
           end = max(tweets22$agg22.date_cli),
          min = min(tweets22$agg22.date_cli),
         max= max(tweets22$agg22.date_cli))

query <- reactive({
 tweets22 %>%
  select(agg22.id_cli, dateW, agg22.val_cli)  %>%
  filter(agg22.id_cli == input$id_cli2) 

})

 newtweets22 <-reactive({
 query()
 filter(tweets22, between(dateW, input$dateW[1], input$dateW[2])) 
})

renderPlot({
  ggplot(newtweets22(), aes(x=dateW, y=agg22.val_cli))+ geom_line(size=1) + xlab ("Date") + ylab("Values") 
})
```

The code takes all the date range of data but does not select by `id_cli` which is `input$cli` Someone can help me please ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal reproducible example, e.g. a complete shiny app (but reduced to your problem)

Comment: in your code, you don't separate the `ui` and `server` function. [Have a look how a shiny app has to be structured](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I added `filter(id_cli == input$id_cli2)` to respond to your update.

Do you want something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("select_ui"),
  uiOutput("date_ui"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  req22 <- reactive({
    # Replace this with your database query:
    tibble(id_cli = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
           val_cli = c(12,30,80,70,50,20),
           date_cli = c(ymd("2020-02-01"), ymd("2020-02-02"), ymd("2020-02-03"),
                        ymd("2020-02-04"), ymd("2020-02-05"), ymd("2020-02-06")))
  })
  
  output$select_ui <- renderUI({
    req(req22())
    clients <- req22() %>% distinct(id_cli) %>% pull %>% sort
    selectInput("id_cli2", "List of clients", choices = clients)
  })
  
  output$date_ui <- renderUI({
    req(req22())
    dates <- req22() %>%
      filter(id_cli == input$id_cli2) %>% 
      summarize(mindate = min(date_cli),
                maxdate = max(date_cli))
    dateRangeInput("dateW", "Select a date",
                   start = dates$mindate,
                   min = dates$mindate,
                   max = dates$maxdate,
                   end = dates$maxdate)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(req22(), input$dateW, input$id_cli2)
    
    req22() %>%
      filter(date_cli >= input$dateW[[1]],
             date_cli <= input$dateW[[2]],
             id_cli == input$id_cli2) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=date_cli, y = val_cli)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I assume that each time the user changes the client ID, you want the dates to default to the widest range relevant to that client.  If you want to remember the user's previous date selections, then you should store them in a `reactiveVal` using `observeEvent` and then also use this in the filtering.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @MichaelDewar. That is solve my problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes I want like this but there is something doesnt Ok.
If I consider your code with this new data :

```
req22 <- reactive({
        # Replace this with your database query:
        tibble(id_cli = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
               val_cli = c(12,30,80,70,50,20),
               date_cli = c(ymd("2020-02-01"), ymd("2020-02-02"), ymd("2020-02-03"),
                           c(ymd("2020-02-04"), c(ymd("2020-02-05"), c(ymd("2020-02-06")))
    })
```

In the user interface when I select `1` of `List of cients`, in the select date range I want to have automaticaly `2020-02-01 to 2020-02-03` and when I select `2` of List of clients I want to see in the `Select a date` automatcaly  the date between `2020-02-04 to 2020-02-06`
The plot is OK, but there is the prolem only in the DateRangeInput.
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @MichaelDewar. That is solve my problem ^^